# Why does StreamWriter.AutoFlush make this print twice?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Why does the below print duplicate messages only when `StreamWriter.AutoFlush` is set to true?

```
using (var stream = log.Open(FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        /****************************/
        streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
        /****************************/
        streamWriter.WriteLine(new string('-', 80));
        streamWriter.WriteLine(file.FullName);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(new string('-', 80));
        try
        {
            await Runner.Run(
                file, // Argument passed in. In this case, points to ConsoleApplication10.exe
                streamWriter,
                streamWriter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the file contents when `.AutoFlush=true` is commented out:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(path removed for security)\ConsoleApplication10.exe
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Out: 1/28/2016 5:19:22 PM
Err: 1/28/2016 5:19:22 PM
```

Here's the file contents when `.AutoFlush=true`. Note the duplicated lines:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(path removed for security)\ConsoleApplication10.exe
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Out: 1/28/2016 5:11:59 PM
Out: 1/28/2016 5:11:59 PM
Err: 1/28/2016 5:11:59 PM
```

There aren't any surprises in the source code for ConsoleApplication10.exe:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Out: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Err: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

Here's `Runner.Run`. Note that it starts the process under a different set of credentials than the current user. Other than that it's just piping stderr and stdout similar to the example given in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx:

```
public static async Task Run(FileInfo executable, TextWriter writerForStandardOutput, TextWriter writerForStandardError)
{
    if (!executable.Exists)
        throw new Exception("The given executable doesn't exist");

    // Start the process
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        // Set up the process's start info
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Domain = DOMAIN, // The domain needs to be specified or you'll get an error that says "The stub received bad data"
            FileName = executable.FullName,
            LoadUserProfile = true, // Set to true so that functionality isn't unnecessarily limited for the credentials this program will run under
            Password = PASSWORD,
            RedirectStandardError = true, // We'll be capturing errors
            RedirectStandardOutput = true, // We'll be capturing output
            UserName = USERNAME,
            UseShellExecute = false, // Can't specify credentials to use unless this is set to false
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };

        // Set up listeners for when output or error data is received
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(e.Data, null))
                writerForStandardOutput.WriteLine(e.Data);
        });
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(e.Data, null))
                writerForStandardError.WriteLine(e.Data);
        });

        // Try to start the executable
        process.Start();
        // Begin redirecting stdout and stderr
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        // Wait for the process to end
        await Task.Run(() => { process.WaitForExit(); });
    }
}
```

I'm using .Net 4.6 all around.

Comment: You're potentially writing concurrently into streamWriter from both output events. That's unsafe. Kind of unlikely that this causes this issue, though.

Comment: Also note, that making Run async is pointless because there's nothing naturally async in it.

Comment: @usr this is a section of code from a larger method. The containing method needs to be asynchronous, so not pointless. Note that the Action delegate being given to .Run will not run asynchronously but blocks the current thread. Also the question is about why this behavior happens, not if everyone likes it

Comment: @usr I'll check if writing concurrently is causing the issue

Comment: @usr, see my answer below. Your suspicion was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@usr's comment to the question is correct. The root cause is writing to `streamWriter` in a non-thread-safe way. Changing `Runner.Run` to this fixes it. Note the presence of `lock` statements to make writes synchronized:

```
public static async Task Run(FileInfo executable, TextWriter writerForStandardOutput, TextWriter writerForStandardError)
{
    if (!executable.Exists)
        throw new Exception("The given executable doesn't exist");

    // Start the process
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        // Set up the process's start info
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Domain = DOMAIN, // The domain needs to be specified or you'll get an error that says "The stub received bad data"
            FileName = executable.FullName,
            LoadUserProfile = true, // Set to true so that functionality isn't unnecessarily limited for the credentials this program will run under
            Password = PASSWORD,
            RedirectStandardError = true, // We'll be capturing errors
            RedirectStandardOutput = true, // We'll be capturing output
            UserName = USERNAME,
            UseShellExecute = false, // Can't specify credentials to use unless this is set to false
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };

        // Create an object for synchronizing writes to the output and error TextWriter objects
        var lockObject = new object();

        // Set up listeners for when output or error data is received
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(e.Data, null))
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    writerForStandardOutput.WriteLine(e.Data);
                }
            }
        });
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(e.Data, null))
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    writerForStandardError.WriteLine(e.Data);
                }
            }
        });

        // Try to start the executable
        process.Start();
        // Begin redirecting stdout and stderr
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        // Wait for the process to end
        await Task.Run(() => { process.WaitForExit(); });
    }
}
```